# DAG Import Errors - Invalid arguments were passed

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-storage, airflow, etl

Im tryng Load data from postgresql(local) to google cloud storage using airflow by docker, but i got error like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHzAF.png

```
Broken DAG: [/opt/airflow/dags/postgres_to_bigquery.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 408, in apply_defaults
    result = func(self, **kwargs, default_args=default_args)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 756, in __init__
    f"Invalid arguments were passed to {self.__class__.__name__} (task_id: {task_id}). "
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Invalid arguments were passed to PostgresToGCSOperator (task_id: postgres_to_gcs). Invalid arguments were:
**kwargs: {'google_cloud_storage_conn_id': 'gcp_conn'}
```

And this is some part of my own code

```
GCS_CONN = Variable.get('GCS_CONN')

default_args={
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'retries': 0,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
    }

with DAG(
    dag_id = 'postgres_to_bigquery',
    default_args = default_args,
    start_date = datetime(2022, 10, 3),
    schedule_interval = '@once'
) as dag:

    start = DummyOperator(
        task_id = 'start',

    )

    postgres_to_gcs = PostgresToGCSOperator(
        task_id = f'postgres_to_gcs',
        postgres_conn_id = 'postgres_localhost',
        sql = f'select * from orders;',
        bucket = 'airflow_fakri',
        filename = f'airflow_fakri/data/orders.csv',
        export_format = 'csv',
        gzip = False,
        use_server_side_cursor = False,
        google_cloud_storage_conn_id = GCS_CONN

    )
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are indeed passing the wrong argument.
From the doc: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/postgres_to_gcs/index.html

The correct conn parameter name is postgres_conn_id